# Create web applications to run R scripts

Tags: r, web-applications

Is there anything similar to the Rwui package to create web applications to run R scripts?

Answer (score 5):

Please do not cross-post simultaneously to r-help and StackOverflow.

As I just mentioned in my reply on r-help, there is [an entire section of the R FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#R-Web-Interfaces) devoted to this question.